# Why must I add a colon for scp to work?

Tags: scp

This command does nothing.

```
scp doc.txt user@mywebsite.com
```

This command, however, copies `doc.txt` into the home directory of my website.

```
scp doc.txt user@mywebsite.com:
```

Why doesn't the first command (without a colon) work?

Comment: You're wrong about the first command. It in fact does something: copies `doc.txt` to `user@mywebsite.com`.

Comment: To clarify why you get downvotes on your question: it does not show any "research effort" which is required on this site, inasmuch as reading `man scp` would have given you the answer.

Comment: I disagree with the comments above. This is a really good question, as you worded it well and formatted it well and it provoked answers which provide clarity beyond what the man pages describe. Upvoted. Thanks for asking it. It helped me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `man` page for [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp):

```
[user@]host1:]file1
```

The host needs a colon to indicate that it's remote.

Answer (score 6):

scp can be used locally. The colon is how it distinguishes between a local copy and a remote copy. BTW that first one probably does something - copy doc.txt to a local file called "user@mywebsite.com"

Answer (score 1):

The name `user@mywebsite.com` is a valid name on the local filesystem.  scp like rcp before it uses the colon character to seperate the remote user and hostname from the remote path.

Or to put it differently, that is just the way the program was written.